# Prevent to continue writing on textbox if the pattern against the Regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a `textbox` for my **passport code**.

How can I define if the code that user entered are not the same with the regex prevent to continue writing on textbox ?

And keep the error till user enters the correct one ?
here is my snippet :

```js
$(".passno").each(function(index, element) {
  $(this).bind('keyup', function(event) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[A-Z][0-9]{8}$");
    var value = event.currentTarget.value;
    if (!regex.test(value)) {
      $(this).next(".box-infoes").find(".error").css("display", "block")
    } else {
      $(this).next(".box-infoes").find(".error").css("display", "none")
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="passno" placeholder="e.g.=J12345678" />
<div class="box-infoes">
  <div style="color:red; display:none;" class="error"> This Is a Wrong passportcode !</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Prevent writing and allow user to type something? Do not frustrate users, check input before submission of form, or leave script as it is...information (error message) is enough...

Comment: prevent writing if user enters wrong character

Comment: In that case you need to check character by character, not whole length string (so, your regex will not help, it can check only whole string, at the end of typing)... So, if first char is not uppercase letter, stop, etc, etc... Actually, you will have to allow typing of only uppercase letters and numbers... And, think about paste in field, too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex should be like `RegExp("[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{8}")` but your code need more modify, such prevent count some buttons like <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>
`AS` character or if it's empty remove the error and etc..

Now regex say: `[A-Z]{1}` just one word + `[0-9]{8}` eight numbers.

*For Example type* ***J12345678***

```js
$(".passno").each(function(index, element) {
  $(this).bind('keyup', function(event) {
    var regex = new RegExp("[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{8}");
    var value = event.currentTarget.value;
    $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
    
    if (!regex.test(value) || value.length > 9) {
      $(this).next(".box-infoes").find(".error").css("display", "block")
    } else {
      $(this).next(".box-infoes").find(".error").css("display", "none")
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="passno" placeholder="e.g.=J12345678" maxlength="9"/>
<div class="box-infoes">
  <div style="color:red; display:none;" class="error"> This Is a Wrong passportcode !</div>
</div>
```

Well, for limit characters length you can use `maxlength="9"` on your `input` or control it with `jquery` `value.length > 9`

Comment: Thank you . Is there a way to start with capital world . I want to type in the textbox only with capital world and send it to server .

Comment: Glad to help you. when you use `A-Z` this mean user should enter *ALL* capital words, include start.

Comment: I mean I want to type in capital word even if the key that user pressed was with small word?

Comment: Now i get it, yes it's possible. let me update my answer. @aynaz

Comment: You should use `$(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());`

Comment: there is a problem with your code. I can type more than 9 character and it does not show the error

Comment: *Aw*, i didn't see the e.g in your `placeholder`, figured out what you want.

Comment: @aynaz Now try.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".passno").each(function(index, element) {
  $(this).bind('keypress', function(event) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[A-Z][0-9]{8}$");
    var value = event.currentTarget.value;
    if (!regex.test(value)) {
      $(this).next(".box-infoes").find(".error").css("display", "block");
       event.preventDefault();
    } else {
      $(this).next(".box-infoes").find(".error").css("display", "none")
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="passno" placeholder="e.g.=J12345678" />
<div class="box-infoes">
  <div style="color:red; display:none;" class="error"> This Is a Wrong passportcode !</div>
</div>
```

Comment: may be problem in you regex pls cross check

Comment: regex starts with a letter in uppercase your code doesn't let to type a letter in uppercase

Comment: wait i am checking

Comment: SEE your original code itself shows error if you type Capital letters

Comment: I cant write code for you. i just suggested you can use keypress event and event.preventdefault if there is an error.

Comment: you can not check full regex on every character entered. so obviusly it will show error untill regex passes.